# $USER is empty when running bash script from php in mac

Tags: php, bash, macos, apache

I want to exec() a bash script.sh from index.php.

When I run the script from terminal:

- $USER is admin.
- security unlock-keychain works.
- codesign without --timestamp=none works.

When I run the script from php:

- $USER is empty
- security unlock-keychain does not work.
- codesign needs --timestamp=none to work.

I have changed httpd.conf:

- User admin
- Group Admin

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to access $HOME of admin when running script from php?

Comment: As @that-other-guy said I tried login, it solved environment variables problem, but still unlocking keychains doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`USER` is not a magic variable that returns your username. It's just set for your convenience by `login`, the program that authenticates interactive terminal logins.

From macOS `man 1 login`:

```
The login utility enters information into the environment (see environ(7)) 
specifying the user's home directory (HOME), command interpreter (SHELL),
search path (PATH), terminal type (TERM) and user name (both LOGNAME and USER).
```

If you don't run in this context, these variables may not be available.

You should either update the bash script to get the username in a more robust way (`id -un`), or you can do `login`'s work in PHP with `putenv("USER=" . get_current_user());`

Comment: I tried login, it took care of environment variables, I have still problem with unlocking keychains. I was thinking the solution for environment variables will solve that, but now I see it does not.

Comment: @AliAsadpoor if you have problem accessing keychain then upgrade your question, or create new one. that may be interesting.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear in my question, I updated my question.